# Is it possible to install a local version of a package at runtime and use said local package?

Tags: c#, console, nuget

As part of trying to test a NuGet package with a Console application, is it possible to have the console application get the latest version of said NuGet package programmatically, and then use said package to call various methods and what not? This is the flow that I'm trying to achieve...

1. A NuGet package is created locally (already done as part of a build process)
2. A console application installs this package
3. The same console application calls a few methods that are inside this package (if this uses reflection insdie the console app to achieve this it isn't an issue)

How can this be achieved? I've tried the following code using the `NuGet.Core` & `NuGet.Protocol` NuGet packages...

```
// exception thrown for trying to resolving newtonsoft
IPackageRepository packageRepository = new NuGet.LocalPackageRepository(directoryPath);
PackageManager pm = new PackageManager(packageRepository, GetExecutingAssemblyDirectory());
pm.InstallPackage("package_id", SemanticVersion.Parse("package_version"));
```

---

```
NuGet.Common.ILogger logger = new Logger();
IEnumerable<LocalPackageInfo> packageInfos = LocalFolderUtility.GetPackagesV2(directoryPath, logger);
foreach (LocalPackageInfo lpi in packageInfos)
{
    // no obvious way to actually install the package
}
```

---

```
// never more than zero packages
var localRepo = new LocalPackageRepository(directoryPath);
var packages = localRepo.GetPackages();
if (packages?.Count() > 0)
{
    var packageManager = new PackageManager(localRepo, GetExecutingAssemblyDirectory());
    packageManager.InstallPackage(packages.ElementAt(0).Id);
}
```

I haven't been able to get any of those pieces of code to work. Is this actually possible? Would I have to look at using 2 Console apps (one to install into the other, which then does the calling of methods), and if so how would this be done?

Comment: I can think of 3 other apps that use NuGet's libraries off the top of my head, so yes, it's certainly possible. Be aware that NuGet.Core is ancient, 2.x-era packages. The current version is 5.x. 2.x can't read semver2 packages, and I'm sure other limitations as well, so possibly you're hitting those. [NuGet is open source](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client), so you'll need to dig around there to figure out how to do things, as the NuGet team's focus are tools, the packages are just there in case they're useful for others.

Comment: If you're only going to load packages that you control yourself, you can avoid needing to do asset selection, but otherwise you need to consider that packages can pack multiple versions of itself, each targeting a different TFM. When you load an assembly, you need to know which one to load, assuming any is compatible with your runtime. Also, if those assemblies have dependencies, you're going to have to deal with assembly resolution because unless you copy all the assemblies into a different directory at runtime, you'll need to tell the runtime where to load each one.